# Jquery validation - addMethod is not working on timepicker inputs

Tags: jquery, validation, datepicker, timepicker

I have a form with two inputs (startTime, endTime), I use timepicker on those.
I wanted to set the endTime depending on the startTime (if the startDat and enddate are the same),
ex: Event is starting today and is ending the same date. If the startTime is 12:00, I don't want the user to be able to select 11:00.

After looking for a solution, I came to the conclusion that is much simpler to add a validation method than trying to disable hours and min depending on the startTime. But for some reason the addMethod is not working.

```
HTML

<div class="col-md-8 mb-2">
  <label for="challenge_start_date" class="control-label font-14 font-weight-normal">Start Date:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" id="challenge_start_date"
      name="challenge_start_date" required>
</div> // and the same is input with id="challenge_end_date"

<div class="col-md-4 mb-2">
       <label for="challenge_start_time" class="control-label font-14 font-weight-normal">Start Time:  </label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control timepicker" id="challenge_start_time"
         name="challenge_start_time" required
</div> // and the same is input with id="challenge_end_time"
```

```
JS
$('#save-event-challenge').off('click').on('click', function (e) {
            let $btn = $(e.target);

            jQuery.validator.addMethod('minTime', function (){

                var startDate = $('#challenge_start_date').val();
                var endDate = $('#challenge_end_date').val();

                if (startDate === endDate) {
                    var startTime = $('#challenge_start_time').val();
                    var endTime = $('#challenge_end_time').val();
                    return endTime < startTime ? false : true;
                }
            }, 'End Time Should be Greater Than or Equal to Start Time');

            $formChallenge.validate({
                rules: {
                    challenge_end_time : {
                        minTime: true,
                    }
                }
            });
```

Currently, with the above code, I don't get the warning message if end time is before startTime (and startdate and enddate are the same).
I've also tried with value, element param, as in documentation, but is not working.

```
let startDate = $('#challenge_start_date').val();
        let endDate = $('#challenge_end_date').val();
        if (startDate === endDate) {
            console.log('equals');//it enters here
            jQuery.validator.addMethod('minTime', function (value, element) {

                var startTime = $('#challenge_start_time').val();
                var endTime = $('#challenge_end_time').val();
                console.log(startTime + 'pp');
                if (element.value < startTime) {
                    console.log(element.value + 'jj');
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }

            }, 'End Time Should be Greater Than or Equal to Start Time');
        }
```

Comment: Looks to be a duplicate of your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75732239/why-function-is-not-entered

Comment: I figured later I had to use new Date() and getTime(), to have a proper format. I will add a response with the corrected code.