# Why function is not entered

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have the following Jquery custom validation method :

```
$('#save-event-challenge').off('click').on('click', function (e) {
        let $btn = $(e.target);

        jQuery.validator.addMethod('minTime', function () {
            console.log('kjbkhb');

            let startTimeStamp = new Date($('#challenge_start_date').val() + ' ' + $('#challenge_start_time').val());
            let endTimeStamp = new Date ( $('#challenge_end_date').val() + ' ' + $('#challenge_end_time').val());
            console.log(startTimeStamp.getTime() < endTimeStamp.getTime());
            console.log(startTimeStamp);
            console.log(endTimeStamp);
            return startTimeStamp.getTime() < endTimeStamp.getTime();
        }, 'End Time Should be Greater Than or Equal to Start Time');

        $formChallenge.validate({
            rules: {
                challenge_end_date : {
                    minTime: true,
                },
                challenge_end_time : {
                    minTime: true,
                },
            }
        });
```

Unless I let the date inputs empty, the addmethod is not entered ('kjbkhb', doesn't appear in console). So to work I must first submit with date inputs empty, the validation errors appear, and after if I complete them, but I let the end time to be less than start time, the error appears. But if I first complete everything and submit, and the hour is not correct, the validation is not made.

Comment: Don't worry about }, ), etc, I didn't provide the whole function so is possible I left some }.

Comment: You should not have `.validate()` inside of a `click` handler.  As the initialization method of the plugin, it makes no sense here.   Move both `.validate()` and `.addMethod()` by themselves into your ready event handler.  I think you may benefit by carefully reviewing the plugin documentation and examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validation needs to be configured before it is triggered.

In your code, you need to move the validator setup

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('minTime',...
```

to before the save click is fired - ideally inside doc.ready

As-is, based on provided code indentation, you only add the validator method *after* you have clicked (during the click handler) so the validation doesn't exist when validation first runs (when you click, before your click handler) - but it is there when you click for the second time.  So the first time (when not blank) it passes as there's only [required] validation.

Comment: It worked what you said, but I don't fully understand...because if I had multiple rules in validate, and the validate is in the on click submit button event, is not like it would only take the first rule to validate...no? I have seen multiple example, with the validation method triggered on submit event...so would be better the validation to be outside?

Comment: No, you can add multiple validation rules - just give them different names (not always 'minTime').  Then all the applicable rules will run when it validates.  The *rules* should be setup/configured separately from the form - ie you setup the rule, then you tell the form which rules to use, then they are applied on that form.   By adding the rule in the click handler, you added the rule after the validation had been applied.

Comment: apparently I still have a problem...the condition is not evaluated right, the end time is greater than  start time, but the error message appears, so the method returns false. I consoled log the start and end variables, and the condition, and it returns ok, true if start is less than end.

Comment: the validator and validate are outside of save click function, but outside in loadmodalactions. My guess is, it returns false maybe because the initial state of $('#challenge_start_date') and end, is invalid (at first are not selected...), idk, ill update my code and provide more details of my code.

Comment: Please add a new question rather than update this one.  You'll be more likely to get a response from someone else.

Comment: in console  startTimeStamp is :Date Wed Mar 15 2023 10:30:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)...

Comment: My bad - I missed where your `()` are - you're doing `new Date(dtval+' '+timeval)` - not `new Date(dtval) + ' ' + timeval`.   When you console.log a date, it reformats it, so it's not actually *stored* as "Wed Mar 15...".  Can you start a new question and include all the code (HTML/script src=) to demonstrate the issue?  See [mcve] (in your new question).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252532/discussion-between-denis-and-freedomn-m).