# validator, condition is not evaluated right

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, datetimepicker

I have a form which contains four inputs (start/end and start/end time).

I want to validate that end time should be greater than start time, if start and end dates are equal. For that I have a method which takes both start date and time values and compares them for validation.

```
<div class="col-md-8 mb-2">
  <label for="challenge_start_date" class="control-label font-14 font-weight-normal">Start Date:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" id="challenge_start_date" name="challenge_start_date" required> // + same but for challenge_end_date
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 mb-2">
  <label for="challenge_start_time" class="control-label font-14 font-weight-normal">Start Time:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control timepicker" id="challenge_start_time" name="challenge_start_time" required> // + same but for challenge_end_time
</div>
```

JS:

```
function initModal() {

  $('#challenge_start_date').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
  }).on('changeDate', function() {
    var startDate = $(this).val();
    $('#challenge_end_date').datepicker('setStartDate', startDate);
    $('#challenge_end_date').val('');
  });

}

function loadModalActions() {

  jQuery.validator.addMethod('minTime', function() {

    let startTimeStamp = new Date($('#challenge_start_date').val() + ' ' + $('#challenge_start_time').val());
    let endTimeStamp = new Date($('#challenge_end_date').val() + ' ' + $('#challenge_end_time').val());

    return startTimeStamp.getTime() <= endTimeStamp.getTime();
  }, 'End Time Should be Greater Than Start Time');

  $formChallenge.validate({
    rules: {
      challenge_end_time: {
        minTime: true,
      },
    }
  });

  $('#save-event-challenge').off('click').on('click', function(e) {
        let $btn = $(e.target);

        if ($formChallenge.valid()) {
          $btn.button('loading');

          const formData = new FormData($formChallenge[0]);
          
...
```

The problem is the minTime method is not evaluated right, on save, even if the end time is greater than start time, the validation error appears, so it return false to if valid. If I console.log the condition in save click function, it returns correct... My guess is that it's a matter of scope, being evaluated right if I move the condition to be triggered on click save button. But I can't move it inside, because then the validation won't be applied on the first click:[Why function is not entered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75732239/why-function-is-not-entered)

Comment: Please provide a *complete* snippet that *demonstrates* the issue.   Your code, with some *minor* changes, appears to work fine.  https://jsfiddle.net/pda54hjr/   Added `<form>` tag / added missing inputs / changed `$formChallenge` (which is not defined in your code) to `$("form")`.   The `rules:` will only apply to field defined - so only `end_time` in your code, added `end_date` as well and the error appears on both.   **Most likely your issue is with `$formChallenge`**?  Please provide a *complete* snippet that demonstrates the issue if you need more help, see [mcve].

Comment: The `.validate()` method should not be inside of `loadModalActions()`.  The `.validate()` method should be called once on document ready to initialize the plugin.

Comment: Depends on where `loadModalActions()` is called - without a complete mvce, it could be `$(() => loadModalActions())`.   Need that *complete* snippet.

Comment: @freedomn-m, the OP was complaining about a timing issue.  Most timing issues with this plugin are caused by the plugin not being initialized soon enough.  When is `loadModalActions()` called and is it being called more than once?  Like you said, we don't have the complete snippet.

Comment: I think you may benefit greatly by carefully reviewing the plugin's documentation and numerous online code examples.

Comment: *My guess is that it's a matter of scope* - no, jquery-validation plugin is globally scoped.

Comment: The problem indeed was that the $formChallenge was not seen...somehow it interfered with the $editFormChallange...even though I had different scripts for each. Eventually I added a find(('#challenge_start_date')...for each variable and now it works. I'm sorry for confusing you, I'll try to provide a better code next time. Is hard to figure what is needed when is not everything in one file...I figured I can skip details like adding tags and show where a variable is defined, if I know these are made correct. Thx a lot for help!

Comment: Thank for the update.  Glad you got it sorted.